# Java swing, JButton does not get re-sized on first button press, but does in on second press

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

Here is a mini project that demonstrates the exact same problem (only 2 lines): https://www.dropbox.com/s/fpgkrr7a4z1zdai/JButton%20problem.zip?dl=0

I have a button in a JFrame class, with this code:

```
correlation.performCalculations(numOfRows, corrResult)
correlation.displayGraph(posBar);
```

correlation is a instance of a class called Correlation, and it has 2 methods:

```
public void performCalculations(JLabel numOfRows, JLabel corrResult) {
    numOfRows.setText("Number of records showing: " + filteredCars.size());
    //
    // some calculation code
    //
    correlationResult = (double) (topPartOfEquation / bottomPartOfEquation);
    corrResult.setText("Correlation: " + String.format("%.4f", correlationResult));
}


public void displayGraph(JButton posBar) {
    System.out.println("I am here");
    posBar.setSize(posBar.getWidth(), 92);
    posBar.setLocation(posBar.getLocation().x, (posBar.getLocation().y - 92));
}
```

So the  problem I have is, when I press the button in the JFrame for the first time, in the output it displays "I am here" but it does not re-size the button or re-locate it, however if I press it again, then it does it (resizes and relocates the posBar button). The JLabels in the first method gets updated in the first click but only in the second click does the posBar button gets resized and re-located.

I get the message "I am here" in the first and second press of the button, but it sets the size and sets the location of the button in the second method on the second press. It does not do anything to the posBar button in the first press.

I don't know if it helps but the JLabels and the posBar button are in different panels.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. If you have any questions please ask me.

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));

        jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addContainerGap(32, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(37, 37, 37)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addContainerGap(47, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));

        jButton1.setText("posBar");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(23, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(38, 38, 38)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(37, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jButton2.setText("Press Me (Twice)");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(51, 51, 51)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton2))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 55, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(43, 43, 43))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(39, 39, 39)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 83, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(51, 51, 51))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(68, 68, 68)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton2ActionPerformed

        jLabel1.setText("Test");

        jButton1.setSize(20, 20);
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jButton2ActionPerformed

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

Comment: You will want to call `repaint()` in there.  Also, is the button in a null-layout-using container?  You will want to post a valid [mcve], code that we can compile and run, for us to be able to determine with confidence what your problem is.  Also note that null layouts are generally frowned upon.

Comment: where should I call repaint? repaint the frame or the panels?

Comment: Again for best help, please create and post that MCVE.

Comment: It will take me a very long to do this which I would do if I did not have a dirty solution for it, I am displaying an option pane in the second method at the end, and when the user presses ok on the dialog box, it displays it perfectly fine.

Comment: Well, you may get a solution without it, but if you don't, then please keep my suggestion in mind. I find that isolating the problem code is the best way to help others find out what I'm doing wrong, but more importantly, the effort often shows me what I myself am doing wrong.

Comment: I am actually going to upload a mini version of it right now. I created it much quicker then I thought.

Comment: I just posted a link to a project that demonstrates this exact problem. Please find it at the top of my post.

Comment: No, sorry but your [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) needs to be posted in your question as code-formatted text. Understand that this is not a *help-me* site but rather a *help-everyone* site, including future visitors, and for this reason (and due to links going dead over time) all code/resources must be in the question itself.

Comment: Its a very basic JFrame application with 3 swing components, and 2 lines of code. I thought it would be easier for everyone to play around with the problem "physically" and see what the problem is, rather having to base it on what I am saying and may miss giving you some information that may help you solve it quicker. I will then I just post the answer to it. I am sorry but from your comment you sounded aggressive and I don't think you even looked at the link I sent, because you would have seen that it's just 1 JFrame class with 3 lines of code, and would have illustrated the problem for you.

Comment: After we get the solution, I will post the answer with screenshots and code if I have to, but for you to give me an answer, I think everyone would prefer to have an actual demo of the problem that they can see exactly what is happening. For any other coding problem, yes of course I will just post the code, but in the case of JFrames, I don't think it is as easy to include everything.

Comment: If you insist on a written demo. Create a JFrame class, add 2 JPanels, in one of the panels add a JLabel in the other JButton and then add a JButton anywhere outside those 2 panels in the JFrame, and in that JButton that is outside the panels, put these 2 lines in it:

jLabel1.setText("Test");
jButton1.setSize(20, 20);

where jLabel1 and JButton1 are the component in their own panels.

Comment: No, your suggestion above won't work since you're ignoring the layout managers which is key to your problem and its solution. Any simple JPanel uses FlowLayout by default, and the behaviors would be vastly different than what you're seeing. The responsibility of creating the MCVE is on the question asker not on the answerer. Please remember that we're volunteers, and try to make it easy for us to answer your questions. You'll understand this better once **you** start answering questions here.

Comment: I've added your code for all to see.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I used the drag and drop functionality on NetBeans.

Comment: And your problem is partially stemming from your doing this. By doing this, you are being shielded from having to understand how Swing layout managers work, which is fine when all you want to do is simple GUI's, but is not so good when you try to push the envelop, as you're doing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're ignoring the layout managers and what they do for component sizing. Your JButton is held within a container that uses GroupLayout and is being sized by that layout and its rules. If you insist on doing absolute sizing and positioning, it must be held within a container that uses null layout. If you're not moving it, this can be a wrapper container/JPanel.

For example:

```
jButton1.setText("posBar");
jButton1.setSize(jButton1.getPreferredSize()); // required if using null layout
JPanel jButton1Panel = new JPanel(); // added
jButton1Panel.setLayout(null); // generally frowned upon
jButton1Panel.setPreferredSize(jButton1.getPreferredSize()); // so wrapper is same size as JButton
jButton1Panel.add(jButton1); // add button to wrapper

javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
    jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addGap(22, 22, 22)
        .addComponent(jButton1Panel)  // ******* note change!! *******
        .addContainerGap(23, Short.MAX_VALUE))
);
jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
    jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addGap(38, 38, 38)
        .addComponent(jButton1Panel)  // ******* note change!! *******
        .addContainerGap(37, Short.MAX_VALUE))
);
```

This only works if you're making the button smaller. For more detailed, larger changes, you'll want to avoid GroupLayout and use more programmer-friendly layouts.

Also note that null layouts and `setBounds()` can create serious difficulties  when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.

---

So bottom line,

1. For `setSize(...)` and `setLocation(...)` (or combined as `setBounds(...)`) to work, the component needs to be placed into a container that uses `null` layout.
2. But having said that, `null` layouts are problematic, and so if possible try to look for and use a better solution -- the exact one which depend on the exact requirements of your GUI.

Comment: It worked! I just changed the panels layout to null and it works now! Thank you very much for your help even if we didn't get there very smoothly. I really appreciate your work.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `JFrame.revalidate()` or `JFrame.repaint()` to refresh your interface and see if it works.

Comment: When I do this, it never re-sizes the button, even on the second click. I added them at the end of calling those 2 methods.

Comment: This isguaranteed not to work if he's using `null` layouts since `revalidate()` acts on the layout managers.